# Create table based on COUNT condition

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables in my database. The table `up_to_date` indicates for each record the number of comments (`commentNumber`) that a specific page (`url`) should contain. The table `comment` contains the actual comments I have in the db with the corresponding url.

```
CREATE TABLE up_to_date
 (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
 url TEXT NOT NULL,
 commentNumber INTEGER)

CREATE TABLE comment 
 (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
 commentMessage TEXT,
 url TEXT NOT NULL)
```

I want to create a table `url_to_update` with the url of pages which I need to update: the number of records in `comment` for a specific page is smaller than what indicated in `up_to_date.commentNumber` for the same page.

Something like

```
CREATE TABLE url_to_update AS
 (SELECT * FROM up_to_date 
WHERE up_to_date.commentNumber > COUNT(comment.url = up_to_date.url))
```

Comment: What RDBMS is this ??

Answer (score 2):

in `SQLite` you can create a table with this syntax `create table Table_2 as select * from Table_1`:

```
CREATE TABLE url_to_update AS
SELECT * FROM up_to_date 
WHERE up_to_date.commentNumber > (SELECT COUNT(comment.url) FROM comment 
WHERE comment.url= up_to_date.url);
```

[Here is a sample which you can see](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/50e80/1)